# Отловить окончание загрузки страницы Gmail

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, gmail

Хочу отловить момент, когда все на странице mail.google.com загуризолось

обычный jquery или нативный js с их событиями отрабатывают чуть, а иногда и намного раньше, чем страница загрузилась действительно.

Пишу гмейл плагин, и мне нужно только после полной загрузки закидывать элементы на страницу и логику приворачивать.

У кого-то есть какие-то идеи, или может кто-то сталкивался?

Comment: Откуда отлавливаете?

Comment: из content-scripts в расширении

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно перехватывать событие `message`:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function onMessage(e) {
    console.log(e);
    if (typeof e.data !== 'string')
        return;
    try {
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    } catch (err) {
        return;
    }
    if (/ready/.test(data.s)) {
        window.removeEventListener('message', onMessage);
        onGmailLoaded();
    }
});

function onGmailLoaded() {
    if (/No new mail!/.test(document.body.innerHTML)) console.log('Oops!');
}
```

[image: console]

Альтернатива - периодически проверять наличие какого-либо DOM-элемента, который появляется лишь после полной загрузки.